# Pagination without default order

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, pagination

I have the code below:

```
$firm_ids = array(81, 96, 18, 5, 105);  
$this->paginate = array(  
    'conditions' => array('Firm.id' => $firm_ids),  
    'limit' => 10,  
);

$this->set('firms', $this->paginate('Firm'));
```

In the results I have the ordering in:

```
5, 18, 81, 95, 105
```

How do I disable the default order if I want to order as initial array ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround on some forum, see if this works:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Firm.id' => $firm_ids),
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array(
        'FIELD(Firm.id,' . implode(',',$firm_ids) . ')'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is order by field. here's the link.

[Order By Field](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/06/10/order-by-field/)

Comment: the matter is to disable ordering

Comment: there is no such thing as disabling ordering. either records are returned as specified in ORDER BY clause or By default. default behavior differs with the implementation, it may be the order of insertion of records or by primary key.